# iPhone - Showing PDF in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

I want to show the PDF file in UIWebView an i am doing that with the code below

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"About Downloads" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webViewContractViewer loadRequest:request];
```

All i want is that my UIWebView Farm height and width should adjust dynamically with the height and width of PDF file so that there should be no vertical or Horizontal scrolling in my UIWebView.

I am getting my PDF file Width and height with code

```
NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"About Downloads.pdf" withExtension:nil];
 CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);
 CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
 CGPDFPageRetain(page);
 CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
```

Can any one help. Is there is any other good approach to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
webViewContractViewer.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: this is weird ! I have a sample project for view pdf and I check this case right now .. its Working !

Comment: yeah scalesPageToFit also work with in my others code. but what i actually want is that i can set my webView height dynamically with the content size of webView's scrollView so that my webView should not scroll horizontally. Can u guide me how can i do this ?

Comment: so if i got your point you want to display the pdf as pages when you scroll vertically yo wanna to display the next page right ?